# How to disable call hierarchy result highlighting

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

If you inspect the call hierarchy of a method (by Ctrl/CMD-Alt-H), all calls in the code are highlighted with a green background. If there are e.g. inline implementations of interfaces in a method call, you end up with huge green blobs in your code editor that seemingly can't be removed. I find this particularly annoying. There seems to be no way to 'clear' the results in the hierarchy window. Also, I have searched the preferences/color settings for a place to disable this feature to no avail. So, is there any way, to either clear the hierarchy search or to turn off the highlighting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To remove the highlighting, put the caret in the editor and press Esc.

The attributes used for the highlighting can be configured under General | Search Results | Search result. You probably don't want to remove the highlighting, because this will also affect highlighting of regular search results. There is no other setting to turn off this particular highlighting.